# Loop diagonally through 2D array in one loop

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, diagonal

**How would one traverse an entire 2D array in one loop**
e.g.

I want to push_back the diagonal elements into a buffer to process: 2 to 2, 3 to 3, 4 to 4 
I have tried doing it in two separate loops but I can't process them together afterwards.

Example 2D array:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
1 * * * * * *
2 * * * * * *
3 * * * * * *
4 * * * * * *
5 * * * * * *
6 * * * * * *
```

So, the buffer for (0,1) to (1,0) would be: one star from the grid

buffer for (0,2) to (2,0): two stars

buffer for (0,3) to (3,0): three stars

and so on...

**note** the buffer is a string.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Do you want the diagonal elements, or as you mentioned here: "all elements between these boundaries" ?

Comment: The diagonal elements. So I push back the diagonal elements between (0,1) and (1,0) and then the diagonal elements between (0,2) and (2,0)

Comment: Please clarify.  The example intends to have data[0][0] as the starting point in the upper left corner, correct?

Comment: in that case, you can use `a[i][n-i]` in a single loop.

Comment: I updated some of my comments and post guys. I start at the upper left corner and loop to the bottom right.

Comment: Once again updated the post since some didn't understand my question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get **all the diagonal elements**, the `for` loop would look something like this:

```
for(unsigned int i=0;i<yourArrayWidth;i++)
   yourSum += yourArray[i][i];
```

if you want the numbers from top-left to bottom-right (so "\"), or:

```
for(unsigned int i=0;i<yourArrayWidth;i++)
   yourSum += yourArray[yourArrayWidth-i][i];
```

if you want the numbers from top-right to bottom-left (so "/").

Where:

- `yourSum` is some buffer you initialize before the traversing.
- `yourArrayWidth` is the width of the array.
- `yourArray` is the 2D array in your example, starting at [0][0].

Answer (score 0):

For an array of `M` rows and `N` columns, you would have `num=N+M-1` diagonals, which can each be obtained through:

```
int num = N+M-1;
int len = 1;
std::vector<std::string> res;
for (int i=0; i<num; ++i)
{
  int startRow = std::min(i, M-1);
  int startCol = i-startRow;
  int len      = std::min(startRow, N-1-startCol) + 1;
  std::string str(len, '\0');
  for (int j=0; j<len; ++j)
  {
    str[j] = arr[startRow-j][startCol+j];
  }
  res.push_back(str);
}
```

with `i=0` being the "/" diagonal at the top-left, and `i=N+M-1` being the diagonal at the bottom-right.